# Passing Bearer Tokens across domains and how to inject them in the WIF pipeline

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, wif, claims-based-identity

I have been implementing a skeleton Claims Based architecture for our services and websites. I'm using WIF, .NET 4.5, MVC / Web Api.

I have the STS (WS-Federation / WS-Trust) and several Relying Parties implemented, and all is working fine.

Now, I want to be able to authenticate in one Relying Party and use that same token (the bootstrap token, I assume) to make Ajax calls to another Relying Party. I can get the Bootstrap Token down in the HTML (is this even a good idea?), and add it to the Ajax call headers as some form of Authentication (Basic, etc).

What I don't know is how to intercept the request in the final Relying party, and "tell" WIF to use that bootstrap token and do it's magic with it (Load, Validate, Authenticate, Authorize, Create Principal, Create Session Token, Write it down in a cooke).

I guess I could do all this by hand using the available classes, but there must be a point where I can just hook up for this. Probably around the SAM / FAM modules, but I can't understand exactly how.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SAML is not a good fit for being consumed in html. The format is complex and relies too much on WS-Security for cryptography. I see more adoption these days of OAuth2 (It was OAuth-Wrap in the past), although is complex as well. If you want to explore that path, I recommend the ThinkTecture Identity Server as a quick solution.

http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2012/11/oauth2-in-thinktecture-identityserver-v2-implicit-grant-flow-with-javascript.html

Thanks
Pablo.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it doesn't quite explain how to actually implement it. No matter what kind of protocol or token you use, there must be a point (I hope!) that allows me to hook into the WIF pipeline  so I can tell it that I got a token already, so use it, instead of redirecting to the IP.

Comment: Hi Pedro. If the Relying party is ASP.NET Web API, it uses the ASP.NET pipeline as any regular web application. The SAM/FAM modules should work out of the box. Otherwise, you might want to try to use a custom HttpMessageHandler implementation that uses the WIF classes internally. That's more work for sure

Comment: @pedro did you resolve your problem about how to inject the token in the pipeline? I am seeking for a solution too. Thanks